# Sending Mouse Clicks to WSL Console Apps in ConEmu

Tags: conemu

I'm using ConEmu with Windows Subsystem for Linux and I'm trying to figure out how to allow mouse clicks to be sent to programs like tmux and vim.  I have set `mouse-select-pane` in tmux (1.8) and `mouse=a` in Vim just like I had in iTerm (I'm a recent OSX convert).  I also have `Send mouse clicks to console` enabled in ConEmu, but it doesn't seem that the click events are being sent to the programs.  Is it possible?

Comment: [BashOnWindows in ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/en/BashOnWindows.html)

Comment: @Maximus Thanks for your response.  I installed the dependencies via the wsl-con.cmd script, but I'm having a few problems.  SuperUser etiquette might require me to take this to the ConEmu mailing list for help with the particular problem I'm now having.